# How to add text around/below a node using tikz-qtree?

Tags: text-decorations, tikz-qtree

I read many examples in tikz-qtree, but I didn't find one which illustrates how to add text around/below a node using qtree. Anyone knows how to draw the following tree using tikz-qtree?

[image: how to draw this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{
every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north,draw,circle,inner sep=3pt},
sibling distance=2cm,
edge from parent/.style=
     {draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},
myleaf/.style={label=below:{\strut#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.{}  \node[myleaf=A]{}; [.{} \node[myleaf=B]{};  \node[myleaf=C]{}; ]]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 4):

I know that the OP asked specifically for `tikz-qtree` but, just in case, here's one possibility showing the approach using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  nodes={anchor=north,draw,circle,inner sep=3pt},
  myleaf/.style={label=below:{\strut#1}},
  s sep=2cm
}
[ [,myleaf={a}] [ [,myleaf={b}] [,myleaf={c}] ] ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]